# Array Manipulation and reordering in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, filter, append

Given an array (for example, [ 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 4 ]), implement methods that
moves the non-zero elements to the beginning of the array (the rest of the elements don't matter)

I have implemented as follows, it works but I wonder shorter way of doing it?

```
import Foundation

var inputArray = [ 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 4 ]

func remoZeros (inputArray :[Int]) -> [Int]
{
  var nonZeroArray = [Int]()
  var zeroArray = [Int]()

  for item in inputArray
  {
    if item != 0
    {
      nonZeroArray.append(item)
    }
    else
    {
      zeroArray.append(item)
    }
  }

return nonZeroArray + zeroArray

}

var result = remoZeros (inputArray: inputArray)
```

Comment: pay attention to the fact that the problem does not specify order, only that non-zero should be first

Comment: @PaulDegnan, could u please illustrate your approach with an example?

Comment: This is a code review. You should post this at https://codereview.stackexchange.com and then delete it from here.

Comment: If the relative order of the elements doesn't matter, then you want [`partition(by:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3017527-partition).

Comment: @Hamish, could u please give an example?

Comment: `inputArray.partition(by: { $0 == 0 })` – note that this mutates the original array in-place rather than returning a new one.

Comment: It can also be achieved by *sorting* the array, but partitioning should be more efficient.

Comment: which one is more efficient in terms of space and time complexity  `partition` vs. `filter`?

Comment: `filter(_:)` allocates a new array, so is O(n) in terms of space and time. `partition(by:)` mutates in-place, so is O(1) in terms of space, but also O(n) in terms of time (as documented). I would expect a single partition operation to be quicker than two concatenated filters though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
var inputArray = [ 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 4 ]

func remoZeros (inputArray :[Int]) -> [Int] {

   return inputArray.filter{$0 != 0} + inputArray.filter{$0 == 0}
}
```